# API wos lite bibliometrix biblioshiny

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to do web scraping with Wos lite API. I have a key. However, the script did not run.
Does anyone help me? I don't know what is wrong with my code.
This is the script:

```
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)

api_key <- "key_here"
base_url <- "https://api.clarivate.com/api/woslite/"

query <- "(TS=(research OR development OR innovation OR entrepreneurship) 
OR TS=(investigación OR desarrollo OR innovación OR emprendimiento)) 
AND PY=[2018-2023] AND C1=(BRAZIL OR ECUADOR OR PERU OR URUGUAY OR PARAGUAY OR 'DOMINICAN REP' 
OR JAMAICA OR HONDURAS OR MEXICO OR COSTA RICA OR CUBA OR 'EL SALVADOR' OR HAITI OR NICARAGUA 
OR CHILE OR ARGENTINA OR COLOMBIA OR VENEZUELA OR PANAMA OR BAHAMAS OR 'FRENCH GUIANA' OR GUYANA 
OR SURINAME OR BOLIVIA OR 'TRINIDAD TOBAGO' OR BELIZE OR GUATEMALA) 
AND (LA=English OR LA=Spanish OR LA=French)"

response <- GET(paste0(base_url, "search?query=", URLencode(query)),
                add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer", api_key)))


if (status_code(response) == 200) {
  data <- content(response, "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
  parsed_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data)
  
} else {
  cat("Error en la solicitud:", status_code(response), "\n")
}
```

The code returns the following statement

> Error en la solicitud: 401

PLEASE! HELP!

Comment: A 401 error indicates that you don't have the proper authorization. You'd have to contact the API maintainers as to the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The WOS API is pretty finicky but has some decent documentation. You're close with the request you've assembled above but there's a few different errors that end up giving you the 401 code. By looking at the actual response we received rather than the status code alone we can see that the API isn't recognizing your key because the response it provides is `"message":"No API key found in request"`.

This is because WOS expects the header of your API key to be called `X-ApiKey` rather than the generic `Authorization` you're using, as seen when requesting the API key originally [from the docs](https://developer.clarivate.com/apis/woslite):

[image]

That changes the error we get from a 401 to a 400 (generic) error, which is harder to debug and probably means there's an issue with the query itself. We can construct the query manually using their helpful tool provided via Swagger under the description tab:

[image]

which allows us to see that we also need to specify the databaseId, the number of records (count) and the starting record (firstRecord) in the query, as well as giving us the proper name for our query parameter (usrQuery).

Assembling this into a full query using `paste` still throws an error but simple queries work (e.g. searching for "potato" topics).

```
query <- "TS = potato"
fullquery <- paste0(base_url, "?databaseId=WOK&count=10&firstRecord=1&usrQuery=", URLencode(query))
GET(fullquery, config = add_headers('X-APIKey' = api_key))
```

which means that there's a problem with the query you've attempted to use as well. In the [advanced search examples](https://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS529AR7/help/WOS/hp_advanced_examples.html) I wasn't able to find documentation for the `LA` or `C1` query parameters, which likely means they aren't supported by the API (maybe the expanded WOS API can handle these?). Refining our query to just those finally gives us a successful search, although without the C1 or LA limitations you requested:

```
query <- "(TS=(research OR development OR innovation OR entrepreneurship) OR TS=(investigación OR desarrollo OR innovación OR emprendimiento)) AND PY=[2018-2023]"
fullquery <- paste0(base_url, "?databaseId=WOK&count=10&firstRecord=1&usrQuery=", URLencode(query))
GET(fullquery, config = add_headers('X-APIKey' = api_key))
```

Hopefully that's still useful - if you can share where/how you created this query I might be able to help figure out how to pass those additional parameters to the API but as far as I can see neither the web-based WOS allows searching by country and the API pretty specifically is limited to just English.